# Subqueries involving multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I want a query to return values not present in another table. I currently run two queries and do the intersection in code. I am stuck with the syntax for multiple columns and presence of statements after `where`

First query:

```
SELECT sid, cid 
FROM  Table2
where used = 0
group by sid, cid
```

Main query:

```
SELECT    sid, cid, count(1) as cnt 
FROM      Table1
WHERE     ##not any pair of (sid, cid) returned from first query##
GROUP BY  sid, cid 
HAVING    cnt < 20 
LIMIT     50
```

What is a complete main query?

Comment: when you say *not any* `sid, cid`, do you mean both or any of the following sid or cid?

Comment: @JW ,fixed that ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT    t1.sid, t1.cid, count(1) as cnt 
FROM      Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON        t1.sid = t2.sid AND t1.cid = t2.cid AND t2.used = 0
WHERE     t2.sid IS NULL AND t2.cid IS NULL
GROUP BY  sid, cid 
HAVING    cnt < 20 
LIMIT     50
```

Comment: `WHERE     t2.sid IS NULL` or `WHERE     t2.cid IS NULL` is enough since you are already using `AND` on the `ON` clause.